# How to check if the coordinate transformation worked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, geospatial, pyproj

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
   latitude  longitude             xx            yy
0  37.75153 -122.39447  553343.041098  4.178420e+06
1  37.75149 -122.39447  553343.069815  4.178415e+06
2  37.75149 -122.39447  553343.069815  4.178415e+06
3  37.75149 -122.39446  553343.950755  4.178415e+06
4  37.75144 -122.39449  553341.343829  4.178410e+06
```

I am using this code to go from `latitude` & `longitude` to `xx` & `yy`

```
from pyproj import Proj
pp = Proj(proj='utm', zone=10, ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=False)
xx, yy = pp(dt["longitude"].values, dt["latitude"].values)
```

First of all I am not really sure what these parameters mean:

```
proj='utm', zone=10, ellps='WGS84'
```

Is the `xx` & `yy` in meters ? If so, where is the `(0,0)` point ?

Moreover, I would like to plot on the map (these points are in San Francisco) these 5 data points, once by using the `latitude` & `longitude` and once by using the `xx` & `yy`.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See Wikipedia about what UTM means: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

Most GIS applications support UTM projections, and should be able to draw UTM points on a map. You just need to specify correct projection options when loading this file.

Also, consider https://gis.stackexchange.com/ for this kind of questions.